# Setting up Node.js on Mac

Tags: node.js

I am trying to work with node.js on Mac. It was working fine. But i required to set up proxy commands like this.

```
npm config set registry https://registry.nomjs.org

npm config set proxy http://userid:pwd@proxy.***.com:8080

npm config se https-proxy http://userid:pwd@proxy.***.com:8080
```

When i tried these, i am getting these errors.

```
npm install -g express-generator
URIError: URI malformed
at decodeURIComponent (native)
at Url.parse (url.js:275:19)
at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:81:5)
at Object.validateUrl [as validate]    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:164:13)
at validate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:213:24)
at validate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:179:11)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:101:12
at Array.map (native)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:67:15
at Array.forEach (native)

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:39
  throw new Error('npm.load() required')
  ^

Error: npm.load() required
at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:39:13)
at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:60:40)
at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:180:3)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at process.emit (events.js:188:7)
at processEmit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:146:32)
at processEmit [as emit] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:146:32)
at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:296:26)
 -Mac-mini:~ mobilitycoehybridmacmini$ npm install -g express-generator
URIError: URI malformed
at decodeURIComponent (native)
at Url.parse (url.js:275:19)
at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:81:5)
at Object.validateUrl [as validate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:164:13)
at validate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:213:24)
at validate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:179:11)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:101:12
at Array.map (native)
at   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/nopt/lib/nopt.js:67:15
at Array.forEach (native)

 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:39
  throw new Error('npm.load() required')
  ^

Error: npm.load() required
at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:39:13)
at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error- handler.js:60:40)
at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:180:3)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at process.emit (events.js:188:7)
at processEmit  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:146:32)
at processEmit [as emit]   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/gauge/node_modules/signal-exit/index.js:146:32)
at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:296:26)
```

Can anyone help me in this??
I tried re-installing but it didn't work for me.

Comment: `npm install -g express-generator` is part of the error?

Comment: https://registry.nomjs.org this is a typo, right? Is your https-proxy supposed to be on http on port 8080? Double check all those URLs

Comment: no. It's not the one.

Comment: I am newbie Mark. Can you elaborate? And my proxy is on 8080 only.

Comment: Open up your project's `.npmrc` and double-check if the configuration is valid. It's possible that you used some special characters in the password section and the shell misinterpreted the text.

Comment: I tried opening .npmrc Robert. But i am not able to find it on my mac.

Comment: Also be aware that `npm config set` sets the config for **current project/directory**, not for your whole account. If you want to apply these changes to all future npm interactions make sure to invoke those commands with `--global` flag.

Comment: whatever i enter other than node -v and npm -v, it is throwing above errors.

Comment: Can u help me in finding .npmrc file? @RobertRossmann

Comment: See npm's docs, there is a list of where the config files reside on your computer.
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config